# fancybox not showing images when screen is smaller

Tags: fancybox, bootstrap-4

The fancybox triggers and shows the images when it's wide screen until you resize down under approx 1000px wide. What did I do wrong? Can someone help? A [live page with a test is here](http://pscompetitiveedge.com/reference-test.html), only the top 6 images in the row under where it says Please, Click The Logos To Read Some Testimonial Letters are code with the fancybox. The stuff below is filler for now.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.fancybox.min.css"> 
<=== the above is in the <head> ===>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"><a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="ltrs/tucscenter.htm">
                       <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-fluid" alt="Tuscon Center" src="photos/logo/tuscenter.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a></div>
   <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"><a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="ltrs/texasdot.htm">
                       <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-fluid" alt="Texas DOT" src="photos/logo/TexasLogo.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a></div>
   <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"><a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="ltrs/ushome.htm">
                       <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-fluid" alt="Tuscon Center" src="photos/logo/USHomeLogo.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a></div> 
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"><a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="ltrs/kimberly.htm">
                       <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-fluid" alt="Kimberly Clark" src="photos/logo/KimberlyClarkLogo.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a></div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"><a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="ltrs/FresnoCollege.htm">
                       <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-fluid" alt="Fresno College" src="photos/logo/FresnoCollege.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a></div> 
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"><a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="ltrs/roswelltoy.htm">
                       <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-fluid" alt="Tuscon Center" src="photos/logo/roswelltoyota.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a></div>
     </div>
<div class="clearfix d-none d-sm-block"></div>

<=== above </body> close ===>
<script src="jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".fancybox").fancybox();
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, fix all JS errors, because any JS error can prevent further execution of the code:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).collapse is not a function
```

Comment: how would I do that? I'm sorry, I don't know where to begin